# Powershell compare months and exclude which are not required

Tags: powershell

I have a text file as shown below. I need to preserve the files which are within 6 months old (from the previous month) and write every other content to other file which are more than 6 months old.

What I've done so far is like:

```
$array3 = 
do {      
    foreach($monthl in $monthlookup)
    {
     $mnthl = $monthl -split '-'
     $m_day = $mnthl[1]
     $m_month = $mnthl[2]
     $m_year = $mnthl[3]
     $m_temp = 0
     $prevmonth = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).ToString("dd-MM-yy")
     while(($m_temp -eq "0"))
     {
      if(($m_month -ge $startmonth) -and ($m_month -le $prevmonth))
        {
         $monthl | Add-Content "C:\each_month_latest.txt"
         break;
        }else
        {    
         $monthl | Add-Content "C:\exclusions.txt"
        }
       }      
      }
  } until ($m_month -ge $m)
```

What the issue I identified here is like: If the current month is 1, then it wont go back to the last 6 months and check, as I use just strings here.

Any suggestions or code improvements, anyone of you can think of..? Would be really appreciated.

**Edit**
monthlookup will look like:

```
testdatabase-30-11-14-23-00
testdatabase-31-12-14-23-00
testdatabase-30-01-15-23-00
testdatabase-31-01-15-23-00
testdatabase-27-05-15-23-00
testdatabase-28-02-15-23-00
testdatabase-31-03-15-23-00
testdatabase-30-04-15-23-00
testdatabase-31-05-15-23-00
```

$m is `$m = Get-Date -Format "MM"`

Comment: why you work with strings here?

Comment: @jisaak: I have tested date compare, but failed. Maybe because that I am unsure of how to work with that. And that made me ask for a help here.

Comment: how does $monthlookup looks like? what is $m?

Comment: @jisaak: Question edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't completly understand what you want to do but here some tipps:

1. `$prevmonth = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).ToString("dd-MM-yy")` shouldn't be done each time within the foreach loop
2. You could extract the date using a simple regex: `[regex]::Match('testdatabase-30-11-14-23-00', '^.*?-(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}$)').Groups[1].Value`
3. Parse the date using `[datetime]::ParseExact` and a format string

So it could look like this:

```
# this doesn't have to be done each time in the foreach loop
$sixMonthBefore = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-6)

foreach($monthl in $monthlookup)
{
    # extract the date
    $dateString = [regex]::Match($monthl, '^.*?-(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}$)').Groups[1].Value

    # create a datetime using format string
    $date = [datetime]::ParseExact($dateString, 'dd-MM-yy-HH-mm', $null)

    if ($date.Month -eq (Get-Date).Month -and $date.Year -eq (Get-Date).Year)
    {
        Write-Host "$monthl is from this month"
    }
    elseif ($date -gt $sixMonthBefore)
    {
        $monthl | Add-Content "C:\each_month_latest.txt"
    }
    else
    {
        $monthl | Add-Content "C:\exclusions.txt"
    }    
}
```

Comment: That's working!!! cool... Thanks a lot. But can I ask you to edit it in such a way that I dont want to come the strings which are of this month, say current month is july (07), so, I dont want to store the strings of this particular month, instead do a write-host.

Currently All the strings less than 6 months old is being stored.

Comment: Awesome.. :) Many Thanks